# Pointing to Address in Python

Tags: python, memory-management

I am doing a form of breadth first search in a directed graph, and I want to store data recursively in the form `(node, parent data*)`. How is this recursive? Starting with the root it will look like `(root, None)`. Then the data for its child will be `(child1, (root, None))`. The child of child1 will then store `(child2, (child1, (root, None)))`.

Obviously as the path length grows this becomes a lot of data. My question is: Lets say I assign a variable to the parent data, say `parent_data = (root, None)` and then write the child data as `(child1, parent_data)`, is the variable storing all the parent data or is it simply a reference that will access the parent data upon request? I don't want to be storing all of this information multiple times.

What I wish I could do was simply have a C++ style pointer where in C++ notation I would assign `tuple * parent_pointer = &(root, None)`.

Is this possible in Python or even necessary?

Apologies if the question is not clear, I am new to CS.

Comment: Your tuples are Python container objects. A container in Python stores references to objects, not object copies.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote world hehe!

Comment: Note also that in Python `.copy` is different from `.deepcopy` (full copy of container objects to any nested level). It only copies 1st level objects (shallow copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `lists`, or `tuples`, or `dict`, or even any custom created class - to store the parent_data, it will use the pointer by default. i.e. it won't copy the data.

Example:

```
In []: parent_data = ['root', None]

In []: child_data = ['child1', parent_data]

In []: child_data
Out[]: ['child1', ['root', None]]

In []: child_data[1][1] = "THIS USED TO BE NONE"

In []: child_data
Out[]: ['child1', ['root', 'THIS USED TO BE NONE']]

In []: parent_data
Out[]: ['root', 'THIS USED TO BE NONE']

In []: id(parent_data)
Out[]: 4705828232

In []: id(child_data[1])
Out[]: 4705828232
```

To do a value based copy, you need to use: `parent_data.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

Python variables are references to objects, this code

```
obj1 = obj2
```

will store a reference to *obj2* in *obj1* - you can check it with the help of *id* function.

The whole idea of Python "by reference" approach is to make issue of memory management mute